# Gurobi Python: How do I do element-wise multiplication on MVar?

Tags: python, gurobi

How do I do element-wise multiplication in the constraint for a quadratic program?

I have the following implementation

```
import gurobipy as gp

m = gp.model("model")
x = m.addMVar(shape=(10), name="x")
y = m.addMVar(shape=(5), name="y")
A = np.random.rand(5, 10)

m.addConstr(A @ x - (y*y) <= A[:,0], name="const")

m.setObjective(x.sum() - (y*y).sum()), GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

The `(y*y)` does not work as it does in numpy for element-wise multiplication, and throws the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/test.py", line 21, in solve_QP_gurobi
    m.addConstr(A @ x - (y*y) <= A[:,0], name="const")
  File "mvar.pxi", line 76, in gurobipy.MVar.__mul__
  File "mvar.pxi", line 152, in gurobipy.MVar.scalar_mult
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'MVar'
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your "y" is a scalar, you can do y @ y